# Automatically merge, synonymize, etc. all amazon-* and aws-* tags to a consistent master tag name

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

There are various synonymous tags for AWS services such as:

- [amazon-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sts) is remapped to [aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts)
- [aws-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ses) is remapped to [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses)
- [amazon-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kms) is remapped to [aws-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms)
- [aws-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-s3) is remapped to [amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3)

and so on and on.

And some services like [aws-appsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-appsync) do not have a synonym at all.

There are individual synonymize/merge question on meta for separate AWS services. But I doubt it would not be an overkill.

It could be nice to have an overall rule or regulation for *master* tags of AWS services rather than zookeeping them on demand.

For example:

> The tags related to AWS services and having synonymous tags will have the master tag as `aws-...`

Comment: Part of the problem is Amazon itself of course. For instance, S3 is called Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) on its website, whereas STS is called AWS Security Token Service (STS). Actually, looking at the tags you've mentioned, the target of all of the synonyms are the Amazon-preferred names (at least according to their site). So, the question is, do we go with Amazon's naming scheme, or the one that makes sense? :).